# flask does not redirect after post

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

im using flask to make an web app, in the main.py i have this

```
@app.route('/id_cap', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def id_cap():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        x = request.form["folio"]
        print(x)
        return redirect(url_for('page_red'))
    return render_template("id_cap.html")

@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    encodes = pd.read_sql_table("Encodes", con=db.engine)
    return Response(gen(encodes), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')   

#edit
@app.route('/enrollment', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def page_red(): 
     with open(target, "rb") as f:
         unpickler = pickle.Unpickler(f)
         name = unpickler.load()
    if name == "noname":   
        if request.method == 'POST':         
            params = {"nombre": request.form.get('textbox'), "folio": request.form.get('textbox2')}
            encodes = pd.read_sql_table("Encodes", con=db.engine)
            id_num = len(encodes)
            encode_subj = functionist()#this make the encodes whit face_recognition library
            encode_pd = encode_creation(encode_subj, id_num, params) 
            row_to_write = list(encode_pd.loc[0])
            row_value_markers = ','.join(['?']*len(row_to_write))
            db.engine.execute("INSERT INTO Encodes VALUES (%s)"%row_value_markers, row_to_write) 
            return redirect(url_for('index'))
        return render_template("enrollment.html") 
    if name != "noname":
          return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return render_template("enrollment.html")
```

and in another file i have this other code

```
    def gen():
        doing some stuff with opencv to show camera....
        url = 'http://0.0.0.0:5000/id_cap'
        myobj = {'folio': folio}
        x = requests.post(url, data = myobj)
        (flag, encodedImage) = cv2.imencode(".jpg", frame)
        yield(b'--frame\r\n' b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + bytearray(encodedImage) + b'\r\n')
```

sadly the page is not redirecting, in the console where the main.app is  executed,  when i go to the /id_cap page i get:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Jun/2020 15:31:42] "GET /id_cap HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Jun/2020 15:31:45] "GET /video_feed HTTP/1.1" 200 -
54254354
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Jun/2020 15:31:48] "POST /id_cap HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Jun/2020 15:31:48] "GET /enrollment HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [02/Jun/2020 15:31:48] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

the integer line here is the x printed on the id_cap()so the post is recived by the app but then it is not redirected, any advice or help here will be welcome

Comment: There's `302` status code, what do you mean under *"not redirected"*?

Comment: srry if my definitions are wrong, i mean that the page does not change in the browser it is still on the same direction /id_cap instead of going to page_red

Comment: You might find enlightenment by examining `x`

Comment: Could you also add your "page_red" route please?

Comment: yes, it is a little messy but let me reduce it a little and then i'll post it thanks for the time

Comment: it is not to much obvious what does the page_red() do but it takes some pictures and data from files and a post method in order to add a row in to a database, srry if it is not friendly i've tried a lot